# Energy reservoir capacitor

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, energy

How to calculate the appriopriate capacitance for an energy reservoir capacitor that would serve as an alternative IC power supply in case of main power supply failure. Is there a specific formula or a method to identify the right capacitor for the application?

The datasheet specifies a minimum capacitance value but I am curious about the general process of identifying the exact or the most appropriate capacitance for the application.

Comment: What datasheet, and where does it say this minimum value?

Comment: it is used for a driver application by TI, it is recommended to use 100uF higher bulk cap for energy reservoir.

Comment: A part number would be nice

Comment: Yes there are formulas. You need the currents and voltages and frequencies or time involved to use them. Please note that sometimes adding more capacitance is not what you want, as it could be the wrong solution, ending up with a humongous capacitor from where you utilize only a fraction of the stored energy. Describing the system may provide a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A capacitor stores a certain charge.

Per charge added, the voltage rises. Per charge removed, the voltage drops.
A charge is a certain current flowing for a certain time.

Circuits require not only current, but also a minimum voltage to operate.

**Therefore, the formula is:**

$$C=\frac{Q}{V}$$

which can be rewritten as:

$$C=\frac{I*\Delta T}{\Delta V}$$

**For your application this means:**

$$C=\frac{I_{max}*T_{min}}{V_{nom} - V_{min}}$$

with

- I_max = Maximum current draw (Amperes) of the circuit to be kept alive
- T_min = Minimum time (Seconds) to keep the circuit alive after power fail
- V_nom = Nominal voltage (Volts) the capacitor is charged too
- V_min = Minimum operating voltage (Volts) for the circuit to be kept alive can operate from

**But:**

Be aware of the significant inrush-currents big capacitors with low ESR can cause. You should have a look at slew-rate controllers, hot-plug controllers, inrush-limiters, soft-starters - many names for a family of ICs targeted at this problem.

**Also:**

Make sure your capacitor does not "pump" its charge towards the power supply, once it failed. LDOs usually don't really like that.

**And:**

If your capacitor is charged to a significant Voltage **V>48V** you should rethink your overall approach. **Touching high charge reservoirs at high voltages is ... not so nice**. Also you should incorporate some sort of bleeding if your circuit to be kept alive does not draw current any more (e.g MCU flushed its memory and goes to sleep).

Comment: @1234 "T_min = Minimum time (Seconds) to keep the circuit alive after power fail"